# Weird Error. Incompatible Types Error on line "return mFragmentList.get(position);"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-studio

I am a newbie. I am following a tutorial on Swipe Tab Activity at http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

I get weird error saying Incompatible Types at "return mFragmentList.get(position);" in MainActivity.java   Please help.

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.pixalstudio.musicadda;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setSupportActionBar(Toolbar toolbar) {
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<android.app.Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(android.app.Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

if anyone need anything else to help, please let me know. thanx in advance :)

LOGCAT

```
    03-04 21:38:22.643 2650-2650/com.pixalstudio.musicadda E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.pixalstudio.musicadda, PID: 2650
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pixalstudio.musicadda/com.pixalstudio.musicadda.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to android.widget.Toolbar
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to android.widget.Toolbar
                                                                             at com.pixalstudio.musicadda.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
03-04 21:38:22.645 1519-1887/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity 1 com.pixalstudio.musicadda/.MainA
```

ctivity

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pixalstudio.musicadda"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
private final List<android.app.Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
```

To:

```
private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
```

You are not using the support fragment there like you are everywhere else.

Same with the `addFragment` method:

```
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}
```

You can replace those lines with just `Fragment` since you are importing the support library fragments `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`.

Also note that `OneFragment`, `TwoFragment`, and `ThreeFragment` must extend from the support library fragment if they are not already.

Based on the new log posted you also need to import the toolbar from the support library.

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

Comment: your suggestion resolved the error, but application crashes while running. I am posting LOGCAT above. Please check what's wrong. Thanx for your quick response.

Comment: @akkie4396 You are importing the wrong toolbar. You also need the toolbar from the support library so the import should be `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;`

Comment: when I try to inport it does not automatically suggest me andoird.support.v7.widget.Toolbar... i have to manually type it and then it shows red error.

Comment: What version of the v7 appcompat library are you using in your gradle file? Also you have a typo in your comment when spelling android. I'm going to assume that isn't what you actually tried.

Comment: its compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'

Comment: That's good. Did you paste in exactly what I put here? `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;`

Comment: Yes I put exactly what u told me and there no typo in actual code.. i already checked it.

Comment: You can also try doing File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart to make sure Android Studio isn't confused.

Comment: I have posted build.gradle... please have a look... till then I ll try doing what you said above...thnx

Comment: That looks good. I even put it in a new empty project and it is finding the `Toolbar` without issue.

Comment: Hi george, how do I add listview for list of the songs in these fragments. Tried to google but couldnot find helpful. thought, if you can help

Comment: Easiest way is to probably search on how to use a `ListFragment` first and maybe just get it to display a list of strings which can be the name of the songs. Once you get that working you can then move to looking on the devices file system for real songs to play and building a more complex layout for each song if you wanted to include more details like the artist and duration.

Answer (score 0):

This is where your problem is. You are using android support library version 7 while the tutorial is using the android widget Toolbar.

android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to android.widget.Toolbar

Change your ToolBar in your layout file to

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Remember to import this

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

Comment: "its already the same as you are saying in activity_main.xml" - Sorry, I don't understand